# Titanium appcelerator : Lazy loading concept in table view while loading data using JSON

Tags: json, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have used Google Places API in order to display various places. I want at a time to display 20 places and when user scrolls the table view and reaches last field I want to add the rest of data and so on. I have created a function which returns the view and works perfectly excluding one thing. When further data is not available then it goes on loading the last data which is already loaded. Here goes my code.

```
Ti.include('Functions/get_lat_long.js');
var myTable = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var next_page;
var nxt_pge_tkn;
var tableData = [];
function json_parsing(url,firsttime,winloading)
{

var view1=Ti.UI.createView({
        //height : '100%',
        width : '100%',
        backgroundColor : '#EDDA74',
        top : '10%',
        borderColor : "black"
    });
//For storing url in case next_page_token variable is invalid

var curloc=Ti.App.Properties.getString("curlocation");
//calling method in order to retrive latitude and longitude of current location
get_latitude_longitude(curloc);
//setting the base url that have been initialized in global.js file
var baseurl=Ti.App.Properties.getString("preurl");
//storing lat and lng file that have been initialized in get_lat_lon.js file get_latitude_longitude function 
var lat=Ti.App.Properties.getString("curlat");
var lng=Ti.App.Properties.getString("curlng");
//Storing radius which have been initialized in global.js file
var radiusmts=Ti.App.Properties.getInt("curradius")*1000;
//setting location type from the value that have been selected in app.js file by user
var loc_type=Ti.App.Properties.getString("curcategory");
//fetching and storing key which have been initialized in global.js file
var key=Ti.App.Properties.getString("apikey");
if(firsttime==true)
{
    winloading.open();
    var completeurl=baseurl+lat+","+lng+"&radius=" + radiusmts+ "&types=" + loc_type+ "&sensor=false&key=" + key;
}
else
{
    winloading.show();
    var completeurl=url;
}


var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();


Ti.API.info("complete url " +completeurl);
client.open('GET',completeurl);
client.onload = function(e) {
       //For getting next_page_token so that next page results could be displayed
      var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      if(json.next_page_token)
      {
        Ti.API.info("Next page token found ");
        next_page=true;
        nxt_pge_tkn=json.next_page_token;
      }
      else
      {     
        Ti.API.info("Next page token not found ");
        next_page=false;
      }

      if(json.results.length==0)
      {
        var lblno_record=Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            text : "No Record Found",
            color : "black",
            font : {fontSize : "25%" }
        });
      view1.add(lblno_record);
      }
      else
      {
      for(var i=0; i <json.results.length;i++) 
            {
            //Ti.API.info("Place " + json.results[i].name+ " Lat " + json.results[i].geometry.location.lat + " Lng " + json.results[i].geometry.location.lng);
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                className : "row"
                //height : "80%"
                });
            //For temporary storing name in name variable
            var name=json.results[i].name;
            //Logic for shortening string in order to avoid overlapping of string
            (name.length>35)?name=name.substr(0,34)+ "..." :name=name;
            //Create label for displaying the name of place
            var lblname=Ti.UI.createLabel({
                //text : json.results[i].name,
                text :  name,
                color : "black",
                font : {fontSize : "20%"},
                left : "22%",
                top : "5%"
                });
             Ti.API.info("Name :- " + name);
            row.add(lblname);

            var add= json.results[i].vicinity;
            (add.length>125) ? add=add.substr(0,123)+ ". ." : add=add;

            var lbladdress=Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text : add,
                color : "black",
                font : {fontSize : "15%"},
                left : "22%",
                top : "30%",
                width : "71%"
                });
            row.add(lbladdress);

            var imgico=Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image : json.results[i].icon,
                height : "90",
                width : "90",
                left : "1%",
                top : "3%"
                //bottom : "10%"
                });
            row.add(imgico);      
            tableData.push(row);
            }
            //setting data that have been set to mytable view
            myTable.setData(tableData);
            view1.add(myTable);

            }
    winloading.hide();
};
client.onerror=function(e){
    alert("Network Not Avaliable");
};

myTable.addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
            var first=e.firstVisibleItem;
            var visible=e.visibleItemCount;
            var total=e.totalItemCount;
            Ti.API.info("Value of next_page_token before loop " + next_page);
            if(next_page==true &&  first+visible==total )
            {
                Ti.API.info("Value of next_page_token in loop " + next_page);
                var newurl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken="+nxt_pge_tkn+"&sensor=false&key="+key;
                firsttime=false;
                winloading.show();
                //myTable.removeEventListener('scroll',function(e){});
                json_parsing(newurl,firsttime,winloading);
                //get_next_page(newurl);
            }
        });



client.send();
return view1;
client.clearCookies();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through your code and I would like to point:

- There is an important issue with the block:

  ```
  myTable.addEventListener('scroll',function(e){

  ...

  });
  ```

  this block is called each time you call your json_parsing function. Because of that you will have several functions attached to myTable scroll event. I'm sure that this isn't your intention. You should put it out of json_parsing.
- About your specific issue you could try to look at the json.next_page_token value in your client.onload function:

  ```
  client.onload = function(e) {
  //For getting next_page_token so that next page results could be displayed
  var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
  if(json.next_page_token)
  {
  ...
  ```

  maybe the value is an empty object {} or a 'false' string that will return a thruthy value. Don't forget that in javascript there are only 6 falsy values: false, undefined, null, 0, '' and NaN.
- In practice this is a minor issue, but in documentation [HTTPClient.onload](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-onload) and HTTPClient.onerror functions must be set before calling HTTPClient.open function
- BTW, you have unreachable code at the end of your json_parsing function, but I think you already know that :-)

  ```
  client.send();
  return view1;
  client.clearCookies(); //Unreachable code
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur suggestion. I have completed the entire lazyloading concept. But there is a problem still that I found out.